# Extract tween values from tween.js

Tags: javascript, tween

If i had a tween with a running duration of 2000ms and i wanted to extract the tweened value at 1000ms, how would i go about doing this?  I am using Tween.js @ http://github.com/sole/tween.js

```
var position = {y: 0};  

t = new TWEEN.Tween(position)
    .to({ y: 300 })
    .onUpdate( function() {
      console.log(position.y);
    });

t.start(); // correctly runs the tween and logs tweened position.y values
```

now, from what i can gather, i should be able to to .update(tValue) and have it log the correct tweened value at the given tValue onUpdate.  Instead, position.y only outputs the starting position value.

The first FAQ question of the Github page hints of this ability, but i can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look at the [tween.js source](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/blob/master/src/Tween.js) reveals that it keeps all of its [tweening functions](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/blob/master/src/Tween.js#L281) in a `Tween.Easing` "namespace", and the default easing function is `TWEEN.Easing.Linear.EaseNone`.

Its easing functions are a little different than what I was expecting, but are pretty easy to use independent of the rest of the architecture, once you know what you want to do.

```
function getTweenedValue(startVal, endVal, currentTime, totalTime, tweener) {
    var delta = endVal - startVal;
    var percentComplete = currentTime/totalTime;
    tweener ||= TWEEN.Easing.Linear.EaseNone;

    return tweener(percentComplete) * delta + startVal
}

var val = getTweenedValue(0,300,1000,2000);
```

Something like that should work.

---

I just remembered I also had a related answer a while ago that talks more about the "theory" of [easing/tweening functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316882/what-is-an-easing-function) if you are interested.

Comment: What were you expecting the easing functions to look like?  This works great for my purposes.  Thanks!

Comment: @CaseyYee a lot of easing frameworks have signature interfaces that look more like my helper `getTweenedValue`, the other answer talks about it a bit more as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `setTimeout()` and make a timer run after `1000 ms`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(position.y);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: i don't actually want to run the tween, just extract the value at a given time.

Comment: Ah. What happens when you replace `t.start()` with `t.update(1000)`?

Comment: it runs .onUpdate, but the position.y value is unchanged.  i can run .update() many times with different time values and it responds exactly the same.

Comment: I looked through the source. Try this: `t._easingFunction(1000)`. What does it spit out?