# How to rotate object with linear (normal) easing?

Tags: jquery, rotation, jquery-easing

Looks like default easing in jQueryRotate plugin is not linear.. Image rotate with slowdown at the end of rotation. So if I use recursive function image doesn't rotate evenly.

Example:

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="rotate_me" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; height: 100px"></div>
```

JS:

```
var rotation = function (){
   jQuery("#rotate_me").rotate({
      angle: 0,
      animateTo:360,
      duration: 1600,
      callback: rotation
   });
}
rotation();
```

Comment: sorry, but I can't include rotate plugin into fiddle. Place the code here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution - it is to add parameter:

```
easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){ 
          return c*(t/d)+b;
      }
```

into rotate function.

Description about easing function you can see here:

[What is an easing function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316882/what-is-an-easing-function)

Answer (score -1):

Using only CSS3 is quite simple: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/isajos/1/edit)** 
might be you can find your answer in this lines?
 (this one is for FF, for other br. add the `-browser-specific` properties)

```
img {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: wowrotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes wowrotate{
  from { 
     transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
     transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, Roko.
But as I understand it's for FF and webkit only? Am I right?

Comment: @StasUshakov with a bit of research you can extend for other browsers (I'm not here to ruin the party) (a plugin would be needed for IE8 and lower)