# How to "smooth" an array with an integer

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
array = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

I want to loop through this array so that it gets a "slope" based on an integer. So if the integer is 2 the result would be:

```
array = [0, 5, 10, 5, 0]
```

If I had a even bigger array:

```
bigArray = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
```

then if the integer is still 2 the result would be:

```
bigArray = [0, 25, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 25, 0]
```

The value of the integer doesn't matter, as long as the array has "smooth" ends to it like shown above. The integer just specifies how many indices are affected.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: @Asaph I don't have any code, because I don't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply count at both ends.

```js
function smooth(array, part) {
    var i;
    array = array.slice();
    for (i = 0; i < part; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i] * i / part;
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = array[array.length - 1 - i] * i / part ;
    }
    return array;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth([10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth([50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50], 2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

One example with sine

```js
function smooth(array, parts) {
    function f(x) {
        // return x; // linear
        return Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 2); // sine
    }

    var i;
    array = array.slice();
    for (i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
        array[i] = f(i / parts) * array[i] | 0;
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = f(i / parts) * array[array.length - 1 - i] | 0;
    }
    return array;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth([20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20], 3), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth([50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50], 5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Bonus: Dynamic generation of the array with callback for *smoothing*

```js
function smooth(length, value, parts, fn) {
    fn = fn || function (x) { return x; };
    return Array.apply(null, { length: length }).map(function (_, i) {
        if (i < parts) {
            return value * fn(i / parts) | 0;
        }
        if (i >= length - parts) {
            return value * fn((length - i - 1) / parts) | 0;
        }
        return value;
    });
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth(5, 10, 2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth(10, 50, 4), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth(5, 10, 2, function f(x) { return Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 2); }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth(10, 50, 4, function f(x) { return Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 2); }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Edit: This code works with formulas from http://easings.net/. For further readings I suggest to visit [What is an easing function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316882/what-is-an-easing-function).

```js
// formula     http://easings.net/
// description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316882/what-is-an-easing-function
// x: percent
// t: current time,
// b: begInnIng value,
// c: change In value,
// d: duration
function easeInOutQuad(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) {
        return c / 2 * t * t + b;
    } else {
        return -c / 2 * ((--t) * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
    }
}

function smooth(array, parts) {
    function fn(f, x, v) {
        return f(x, 1000 * x, 0, v, 1000)
    }

    var i;
    array = array.slice();
    for (i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
        array[i] = fn(easeInOutQuad, i / parts, array[i]) | 0;
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = fn(easeInOutQuad, i / parts, array[array.length - 1 - i]) | 0;
    }
    return array;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth([20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20], 3), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth([50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50], 4), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(smooth([50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50], 5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the "slope" itself also be more round, so it's not just a straight line, but more of a curved one? (If we use a graph as the context)

Comment: @SebastianOlsen, yes, if you have a formula for this purpose, then its possible. it just a value necessary between to values (y) and some distance (x).

Comment: Ah. For some reason it appears to be applying the very first indexes of the array to the end: http://puu.sh/nIzKe/42c902e263.jpg

Comment: which version are taking?

Comment: The sine one... on second take it appears to be doing it in your first example as well (without the sine)

Comment: i changed the first two codes. it takes now the actual value of the item and applies the calculation on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106467/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-sebastian-olsen).