# Javascript: increment a variable in a not linear way without Jquery easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, animation, easing

I managed to increment a variable in a not linear way using [jQuery easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) like this

```
var currentAngle = 0 
$(currentAngle).animate({ currentAngle: 180}, { // from 0 to 180 in 2sec
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'easeOutBounce',
    complete: function(){
        movingarm = false;
        animatingArm = false;    
    }
});
```

I'm trying to do it without using Jquery now, pure javascript would be ideal.
Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "variable"? Do you actually want to animate a CSS property?

Comment: What's wrong with jQuery when it does the job? What have you tried to get rid of it? Did you look into the sources to see what your call does?

Comment: i want to increment a javascript variable containing a numeric value. It's not for a css property.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-linear"? Do you want to use trigonometric trajectory or what?

Comment: @Bergi Me and my friends moved our app to angular and are currently trying to do without any jQuery.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171I want to use things like bezier curves or anything alowing to increment fast at start and slow at the end for exemple.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of scripts that do this available on the web, sometimes wrapped nicely into libraries. Have you searched for them? What have you found?

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately didn't found any, maybe i am not using the correct keywors here. Do you have some examples ?

Comment: you could have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497765/pure-javascript-animation-easing/38498793#38498793

Comment: @AlaricB [javascript easing](https://www.google.de/search?q=javascript+easing) gets me some good hits

Comment: @NinaScholz Thx, at first sight it may do the trick !

Comment: @Bergi Thx, i remember thoses, just didn't understood how i could use thems, but with NinaScholz link i may have understood how to.