# Transform slider linear values to exponent

Tags: javascript, math

I have a slider:

```
min val. = 0
max val. = 20'000
step = 0.1
```

`min`, `max` values and `step` are `constants`.
On each step (i.e. thumb position change) slider returns a current value and a thumb position in %.

How can I transform the current returned value to make it grow exponentially like on the 2nd graphic - where 0 - 8'000 - take 80% of slider width.

Red graphic:

> On each step (thumb position change) slider returns a current value
>   and a thumb position in % - current value grows linearly depending on
>   the thumb position.

Green graphic:

> This is what I need. I can only use current thumb position and current
>   slider value as a function arguments.

[image]

Comment: How did you make that graph? What function did you use?

Comment: `var ratio = thumb / length;

      Math.max(minimumValue,
        Math.min(maximumValue,
          minimumValue + Math.round(ratio * (maximumValue - minimumValue) / step) *step`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [easing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497765/pure-javascript-animation-easing/38498793#38498793).

- Easing formulas: http://easings.net/
- Description: [What is an easing function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316882/what-is-an-easing-function)

```js
// formula     http://easings.net/
// description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316882/what-is-an-easing-function
// x: percent
// t: current time,
// b: beginning value,
// c: change in value,
// d: duration

function easeOutQuart(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t - 1) + b;
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i <= 20000; i += 1000) {
    console.log(i, i * 100 / 20000, easeOutQuart(null, i * 100 / 20000, 0, 100, 100));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, totally valid solution. As well as this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2231114